# Cannot access defined property of personnal class

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mkannotation

The thing is that I have a main class : `MyAnnotation`, created to display annotations on my mapView.

```
@interface lieuAnnotation : MyAnnotation

@property(readonly, nonatomic) UIImage *uneImage; // I cannot access this property.

@end
```

I created a second class `lieuAnnotation` inheriting from this one with a new property (an `UIImage`).

```
@interface MyAnnotation : NSObject<MKAnnotation> {

    // Some variables
}

// Some methods

@end
```

On the map, when the pin is selected, I have set a disclosure indicator who calls the delegate method :

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view
                      calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
    [self detailPinVue:view]; // Personnal method
}
```

**Note that the disclosure indicator is only displayed for `lieuAnnotation` instances**

So `view.annotation` should be a `lieuAnnotation` instance.

Then I want to access my property :

```
- (void)detailPinVue:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [aView addSubview:view.annotation.uneImage];
}
```

The things is **I can't access the property `uneImage`** because Xcode tells me :

**Property 'uneImage' not found on object of type 'id'**

But in my mind, it should be possible !

So I also tried to access it with that way :

```
lieuAnnotation *anno = [[lieuAnnotation alloc] init];
anno = view.annotation;

[aView addSubview:anno.uneImage];
```

But it's not working…

Thanks for help and ideas.

Comment: You need to cast it before accessing the property.

Comment: Just use: `lieuAnnotation *anno = (lieuAnnotation*)view.annotation;`

Comment: Additionally, uneImage is a UIImage which addSubview does not accept (it needs a UIView or UIView subclass).

Comment: @AnnaKarenina you're right…

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
if ([view.annotation isKindOfClass:[lieuAnnotation class]]) { 
    lieuAnnotation *annotaion = (lieuAnnotation *)view.annotation;
    [aView addSubview:annotation.uneImage];
} else {
    NSLog(@"error %@ / %@", NSStringFromClass([view class]), NSStringFromClass([view.annotation class]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: You need to cast it before you access the property (but only do this if you are 100% sure the object in question has that property, otherwise you would get a `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at runtime.

Explanation: the object in question seems to have the type `id` at compile time. `id` is a generic type for all objects in ObjC. Not all classes have an `uneImage` property, so the compiler can't tell if an `id` object has that property. What the compiler thinks: "let's play it safe and just don't build". Bottomline: you're smarter than the compiler (as you probably already now).

Fix:

```
- (void)detailPinVue:(MKAnnotationView *)view
{
    [aView addSubview: (lieuAnnotation *)view.annotation.uneImage];
}
```

Comment: It keeps crashing, I'm probably not smarter…

Comment: What does it say? If says `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` I can't help but say 'I told you so'! :) @Lucien

Answer (score 0):

Check the way your annotation, by `MKMapView addAnnotations:`. Make sure that you're adding objects of your custom class.

And you can use `NSLog(@"%@", view.annotation.class);` to know the base class of the annotation.

BTW. The way you cast isn't necessary.

`lieuAnnotation *anno = (lieuAnnotation *)view.annotation;`

 is the correct way.